# Is there a way to get System.out.print(); value from a For loop;

Tags: java, string, for-loop

I'm making a guess the String program game, and I need to convert the users inputted string from letters and whitespaces/spaces to question marks(?). How would I go about that?

I used a for loop and it gave me what I wanted but I can't use the output of the for loop outside the loop.

```
System.out.println("Please enter a string of words.");

        String userString = scan.nextLine();
        userString=userString.toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(userString);

        int s1 = userString.length();
        System.out.println(s1);
        for(int a=0;a<s1;a++) {
            System.out.print("?");
        }
```

I entered "this is a string" for userString.
When I run the program, it outputs:
???????????????? 
Is there a way to turn this output into a String?
Or is there a better way of converting String values into "?"?

Comment: You could store it in a variable and output the variable. In terms of converting string to `?`s, you can try [`String.replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll\(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String\))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to print `?` for every character. You can just replace every char with a `?` and generate a new string without printing.

```
String newUserString = userString.replaceAll(".","?");
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 11 provides repeat() method.

You can use

`“?”.repeat(s1)` inside sysout

`System.out.print(“?”.repeat(s1))` and can remove the for-loop

It will repeat the ? s1 times.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace every character of a String with `?`, you can try

```
String newString = userString.replaceAll(".", "?");
```

The `"."` is a regular expression that will match any character except a newline, which your String won't contain anyway.

Answer (score 0):

from what i understood it i think you want to store the "?" ,
to do that
create a string var outside the for loop
and append '?' in it.

```
String temp="";
for(int i=0;i<s1;i++)
{
temp=temp+"?";
}
System.out.println(temp);
```

this should store the string in temp.

Answer (score 0):

replace all is the correct answer, but if for some reason you HAD to do a for loop you could use StringBuilder and append a ? for each character in the string like so:

```
String userInput = "myString";
StringBuilder myBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for(int x = 0; x<userInput.length(); x++){
   myBuilder.append("?");
}
String myNewString = myBuilder.toString();
```

But the replace all answers above are the right way to do it.